# Create an exe Installer for a website Wamp

Tags: php, mysql, windows, codeigniter, exe

what i need to do is create an installer for my website, i have my website developed in codeigniter and my database in mysql, and is running in wamp php 5.5

Is it possible to create an exe installer that can do this?

```
1.- install wamp, if it is not installed
2.- copy mywebsite folder to www wamp, for example C:\wamp\www\
3.- create database from database.sql
```

Clients ask me for this kind of installer,but i don't know if this is possible, any idea or help , would be really appreciated or software to create installers , thanks

Comment: Anything is possible.  It only depends how much effort you want to put into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate the WIX Installer.  http://wixtoolset.org/  It's a good start creating complex MSI\EXE setup packages and install wizards on Windows that can also install other applications and files as part of your package.

What you describe seems like it would fit within WIX.